# Atrribute Error in Python 2.73 when creating random string

Tags: python

I'm using the following function (which I think is pretty straight-forward) to generate a random string:

```
import sys
import string
import random

    def random(size=16):
        lst = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(size)]
        str = "".join(lst)
        return str
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Google doesn't seem to help, and I'm too new to Python to troubleshoot it effectively myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the `import random` with your function definition.

The 'random' name in the Python namespace is now referring to you function not the `random` module which you intended.

Change the function name to something like `random_str`

Comment: Oh wow. How silly of me. Thanks. I'm used to working with PHP where I don't have to worry about these things.

Comment: Yeah, this tends to happen quite a lot, until you get used to the fact that pretty much everything in python is just a name, and you can redefine the names willy nilly.

Comment: Yup. The error makes sense now too, although at first glance Python's errors could be more intuitively formulated. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah I think a lot of programming languages could do with clearer error messages, especially with people not familiar with the language

Answer (score 1):

You are using the name `random` for your function when it is also the name of the module. Rename your function to something else and it will work.